# Laravel String helper returns object

Tags: laravel

When I do this:

```
$test = Test::create([
  'email' => Str::of($this->email)->trim(),
]);

dd($test->toArray());
```

I get this:

```
array:14 [▼
  "email" => Illuminate\Support\Stringable {#669 ▼
    #value: "test@test.com"
  }
]
```

The problem is that I'm passing `$test` to an event, and in that event `$event->test->email` is empty when I for instance send it in a Slack notification. I'm guessing because it's an object and not a string?

I know that I can use PHPs `trim()`, but I have some more complex Str helpers that I chain which is really helpful. How can I make sure the end result is a string and not an object of `Stringable`?

Preferably directly when using `Str::of($this->email)->trim()`, and not for instance doing something like `public string $email;` in the event because as indicated I use multiple parameters and don't want to convert them all separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to cast it as `string` using `(string)` or `__toString()` like

```
$test = Test::create([
  'email' => (string)Str::of($this->email)->trim(),
]);
```

```
$test = Test::create([
  'email' => Str::of($this->email)->trim()->__toString(),
]);
```

Answer (score 3):

If someone like to took laravel's way to make it works.

There is a `toString()` method (also a `value()` alias to `toString()`) in `Illuminate\Support\Stringable` which the `Str::of()` returns, can make the `Stringable` object back to string.

Simple example:

```php
$str = str()->of('Laravel')->lower()->toString();
```

From [laravel api](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Support/Stringable.php#L1143).